# Create QMenu class outside of main UI

Tags: qt, menu

First off all I want to mention that i'm from java background.

I'm designing my first app in QtCreator, and I want to add menus to it.

I want to create a QMenu widget in a separate file, so as to keep my main UI window simple and clean.

This is possible by defining the QMenu in an xml file and  then including it in main .ui file using a file(load) method, or something similar.

However in QT creator I can't find how to create a new file that inherits from QMenu?

what is the correct way to do it?

I want each components to be simple and specific.

so the UI will simply be the 'main' method entry point, it will draw the main window, and include the initial menu item, I intend to show a simple 'welcome' type page having a menu item connected to a data source.

I expect the menu contents to change depending on the type of data, (or rather the part of the program that the user is acting with). I intend to handle these different menu's in different files related to user interaction.

Thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to use QMenuBar that represents main menu or QMainWindow. QMenu itself is usually not embedded in other widgets.

This is quite possible. Create a designer form class derived from QWidget. Let's call it `My_menu`. Open UI file using text editor and replace QWidget to QMenuBar in the line `<widget class="QWidget" name="My_menu">`. You also may need to remove title property and other properties that cannot be applied to QMenuBar. Now switch to CPP and H files and make your class be derived from QMenuBar instead of QWidget.

Next, open main window UI in the form editor, find QMenuBar entry in the object tree and choose "Promote to" in its context menu. Type your new class name and apply. It should work now.

Files should look like that:

Header:

```
#include <QMenuBar>

namespace Ui {
class My_menu;
}

class My_menu : public QMenuBar
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit My_menu(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~My_menu();

private:
  Ui::My_menu *ui;
};
```

Source:

```
My_menu::My_menu(QWidget *parent) :
  QMenuBar(parent),
  ui(new Ui::My_menu)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

My_menu::~My_menu()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>My_menu</class>
 <widget class="QMenuBar" name="My_menu">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>135</width>
    <height>94</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <widget class="QMenu" name="menuC">
   <property name="title">
    <string>c</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionA">
   <property name="text">
    <string>a</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionB">
   <property name="text">
    <string>b</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <addaction name="actionA"/>
  <addaction name="actionB"/>
  <addaction name="menuC"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a path to take, I didn't know about the 'promote to' option. I'll give it a try. and report back